# Square box symbol displaying as an emoji on phone screen?

Tags: javascript, fonts, character-encoding, samsung-mobile, mobile-website

I have a very simple webpage (HTML/CSS/JavaScript) that uses the symbol "☐" (edit: I believe it's the [ballot box symbol](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2610)), but when I view the webpage on my phone, it shows up as an emoji that looks like a card is being put into a box (image below).

[image]

I've noticed that when I use the symbol in a word document, for example, and open the document in Google Docs app on my phone, the same thing happens, so I'm wondering if there's a way to force the character "☐" to display as a square box on my phone as well for my webpage. (I have an Android phone.)

Additional info: Here's what the symbol looks like in the Google Docs app on my phone:
[image]
And this is what they're supposed to look like (i.e. on my computer):
[image]
Same thing happens when I send that symbol to someone, say, on Messenger - it'll display as a box on the computer, but as an emoji on my phone. That's why I'm wondering if it's just an issue with the phone.

**Edit/update:** [Here](https://github.com/pearl6527/engl483-scrapbook) is my repository. The symbols appear in the file correspondences.js. Currently I've replaced all of the ballot box symbols (☐) with the white square symbol (□), and am simply setting their font sizes larger (since the square symbol is smaller than I'd like it to be). The square symbols display as squares on my phone, though the spacing is a little off when I view them on my phone versus on the computer or using an Apple device. So if there is a way to get the ballot box symbol to work, I'd prefer using that.

Comment: Isn't this just a font thing? They ways emojis render are based on fonts. Lots of renderers have font layers and if one layer doesn't provide a rendering of a character, it just goes one layer down to look for one. What fonts are active in each of these applications? Lots of fonts don't provide emoji and usually people use/create dedicated emoji fonts. What emoji fonts are active?

Comment: I think you're right. I think Samsung phones just displays the character as an emoji instead of a box. I think I will change the symbol to the square symbol and adjust the font size instead. Thank you!

Comment: What happens if you paste that character into this site: https://onlineunicodetools.com/convert-unicode-to-code-points? It will show what code point a character is. Then search up what that unicode code point is in a site like https://unicode-table.com/. What do you see when you do that?

Comment: Your image looks like [`` (U+1F5F3, *BALLOT BOX WITH BALLOT*)](https://unicode-table.com/en/1F5F3/) rather than `☐` (U+2610,  *Ballot Box*)…

Comment: The symbol you put in the first sentence of your question is U+2610, which is not defined in Unicode as an emoji (even optionally). See https://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/emoji/emoji-data.txt. As JosefZ said, the image you showed is U+1F5F3. That character can optionally be displayed either as emoji or as a non-emoji symbol. If you want 1F5F3 to appear as a non-emoji symbol, then you can use the character sequence <1F5F3, FE0E>, or pick an appropriate non-emoji font.

Comment: According to [this site](https://emojipedia.org/ballot-box/), that symbol is displayed as an emoji on Samsung.

Comment: @user I'm not sure what you meant by "applications." The font-family I'm using to display the relevant portions of the webpage is ['Times New Roman', Times, serif]. I don't know what emoji fonts may be active on my phone to have caused this.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/pearl6527/engl483-scrapbook) is my repository. The symbols appear in the file correspondences.js. Currently I've replaced all of the ballot box symbols (☐) with the white square symbol (□), and am simply setting their font sizes larger (since the square symbol is smaller than I'd like it to be). The square symbols display as squares on my phone, though it the spacing is a little off when I view them on my phone versus on the computer or using an Apple device. So if there is a way to get the ballot box symbol to work, I'd prefer using that.